# iOS how to implement a drawer like in iPhone Game Center app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, game-center

I would like to implement a drawer that operates like in iPhone Game Center app. When you pull a `UITableView` then providing that we have reached the top of the table there is this drawer sliding that shows more content.

I tried a few solutions here, all of them kinda work but I can't recreate the same functionality as in Game Center example. I tried to embed a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` - this scroll view has one view on top that plays the drawer role and a tableView beneath. I setup the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for both my big scrollView and a tableView and managed to synchronize contentOffsets of both. I have disabled scrollBars for my big scrollView so I can only see scrollBars from my tableView.

Then I tried with setting a tableView as a subview of the whole view and setting another view - a drawer view as a subview of the same view and again played with `UIScrollViewDelegate` of the tableView to adjust frames of both views.

Both solutions kinda work but it is not what I was looking for. What I consider the biggest flaw of both solutions is that when I pull my tableView to reveal the drawer I can see clearly that I am not interacting with my tableView scrollView because the scrollBars stay on top in the same position during the whole dragging process. When the drawer is fully expanded I can now interact with tableView scrollView (tableView content scrolls and scrollBars are moving)

If you look at attached pictures you can see that in Game Center app scrollBars are moving when the drawer is expanded. It's like the drawer is a part of the tableView's scrollView but when fully expanded stops moving and if I keep pulling this tableView I get more space between the tableView and the drawer. If you push the tableView up in order to hide the drawer the scrollBar goes down.

I would like to implement a drawer that operates like in iPhone Game Center app. When you pull a `UITableView` then providing that we have reached the top of the table there is this drawer sliding that shows more content.

I would like to replicate a viewController like this in Game Center. If anyone knows how to do it than please share the solution.

You can see the screenshots here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O44IS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDf7v.png

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Post directly on imgur.com and link to it, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found exactly how they did it in Game Center app. My solutions works the same and is very simple to implement.

First I made a `UITableViewController` subclass added a `UIView` property called "blueView" and made some adjustments to `tableView` property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -100.0, 320.0, 100.0)];
    self.blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.tableView addSubview:self.blueView];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];

}
```

Then in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method I am adjusting the view according to `scrollView.contentOffset.y` so it stays always on top.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -100) {
        self.blueView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, 320.0, 100.0);
    } else {
        self.blueView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -100.0, 320.0, 100.0);
    }
}
```

Voila! Maybe that will save somebody's time.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewController has to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and inside the `scrollViewDidScroll` method you have to do some calculations.
The code below is from an old project:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y; // this is the important number.
    if (scrollOffset>=0 && scrollOffset<=topHeight) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollOffset/2, 320, topHeight - scrollOffset/2);
        photos.frame = frame;
    } else if (scrollOffset>topHeight) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
        photos.frame = frame;
    } else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, topHeight);
        photos.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Based on your feedback I think the best option is something like this:

```
|----------------------|  
|        DRAWER        |  
|----------------------|  
|                      |  
|                      |  
|                      |  
|     UIScrollView     |  
|                      |  
|                      |  
|                      |  
|----------------------|
```

And inside `scrollViewDidScroll` change the frame of the drawer based on the offset.

Comment: I tired this in one of my solutions. The scrollBar is moving right with my tableView which is not desired...

Comment: put the "drawer" outside the UIScrollView and based on `scrollOffset` calculate the frame and apply it to the drawer.

Comment: or, even better maybe, put one `UIScrollView` inside another. The "mother" has the scrollBar hidden, and the second one not, and apply the math on the "mother" :)

Comment: Andrei, this is exactly what I did in one of my solutions but it feels not the same as in Game Center app. The problem is when you scroll the "mother" the scrollBar on the child stays static (because we are changing whole child's frame and not scrolling it's view. In Game Center app it seems like the drawer belongs to tableView's scrollView... I wonder if I could use tableView header and force it to stay on top with Auto Layout or something...

Comment: Even with AutoLayout I don't think you can accomplish this.
In my opinion your best option is with `scrollViewDidScroll` and setting the frame of the top view based on the scrollOffset. I'll update the answer to explain better.